# Has anyone had experience with this particular monitor? Raspberry Pi Monitor Format Issues

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm building a little device involving a Raspberry PI 3B connected to [this monitor.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09YJ37SBH)

Images:

[Front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxifb.png)

[Back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZyC4.png)

It's a 7.4" HDMI Display, which connects to the Pi with a ribbon connector through the HDMI port.

Basically its working, but the display is shifted like an inch and a half to the right.

Here is what I wrote in the config.txt file to try to format it:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
hdmi_timings=1280 0 64 2 18 400 0 10 3 42 0 0 0 60 0 37330000 3
hdmi_drive=1
```

If anyone could suggest how I could fix it, that would be awesome. Let me know if anyone's had a similar issue and knows any solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is off-topic on Stack Overflow as it is not about software development. I would recommend that you delete this question and re-ask it on [raspberrypi.se].